# How to get price data from this serialized array PHP in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, shortcode

Hi I'm making a WordPress rental villa website and I try to make a price table by season. Prices in the database as serialize and I would like to draw prices separately with shortcode. Is there someone who can help? how to make this shortcodes?

these are the values of a villa in the DB

```
('meta_id' => '3307','post_id' => '426','meta_key' => 'mphb_season_prices','meta_value' => 'a:12:{i:0;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"252";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:422;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:1;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"253";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:422;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:2;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"254";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:422;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:3;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"255";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:493;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:4;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"256";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:493;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:5;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"257";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:708;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:6;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"258";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:893;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:7;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"259";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:893;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:8;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"260";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:708;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:9;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"261";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:565;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:10;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"262";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:465;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:11;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"263";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:422;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}}')
```

i use this shortcode; (but it doesn't work)

```
function fiyatlar_shortcode_function() {
$var    = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mphb_season_prices', true);
$var    = unserialize($var);
$season = 252; // 252 january, 253 february, 254 march...

   $foo = array_column($var, 'price', 'season');

}          

print_r($foo[$season]['prices'][0]);

add_shortcode( 'fiyat_tablosu', 'fiyatlar_shortcode_function' );
```

--Suggestions--

Suggestion 1)

```
function fiyatlar_shortcode_function() {
$var    = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mphb_season_prices', true);
$var    = unserialize($var);
$season = 252; // 252 january, 253 february, 254 march...
    $foo = array_column($var, 'price', 'season');
return ($foo[$season]['price']['prices']); 
}

add_shortcode( 'fiyat_tablosu', 'fiyatlar_shortcode_function' );

//Output: Error Message;
Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /home/
```

Suggestion 2)

```
function fiyatlar_shortcode_function() {
$var = get_post_meta( 426, 'mphb_season_prices', true); 
$season = 252; // 252 january, 253 february, 254 march...
    $foo = array_column($var, 'price', 'season');
return $foo;
}

add_shortcode( 'fiyat_tablosu', 'fiyatlar_shortcode_function' );

//Output: Array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try Below and Let me know .**

```
function fiyatlar_shortcode_function() {
    $var    = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mphb_season_prices', true);
    $var    = unserialize($var);
    $season = 252; // 252 january, 253 february, 254 march...

       foreach ($var as $key=> $value){
                $season_array[] = $var[$key]['season']; 
                $prices_array[]=  $var[$key]['price']['prices'][0];
                $array_combo  = array_combine($season_array,$prices_array);

            }          

        return $array_combo[$season];
        }

        add_shortcode( 'fiyat_tablosu', 'fiyatlar_shortcode_function' );
```

Fiddle

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/k9gq-4abf

Comment: i tried this code and it is give this error massage; Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/tatilbalayi/...

Comment: Check the updated one, need to change the variable names.

Comment: i checked it but it is same

Comment: check fiddle above it will show 422 output as per 252 price

Comment: Yes it is giving 422 and it is correct result. My first season price is 422 TL but why is it give me this error message when i use "get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mphb_season_prices', true);" instead serialized code?

Comment: That is a different issue, What error you are getting when you retrieve it?

Comment: actually i have written before. it is "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/..."

Comment: what result you get when you print - >     $var    = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mphb_season_prices', true);

Comment: it gives nothing when I just write this code. i guess there is problem in the serialized code (it is above)

Comment: Check if your post id is correct or try $var    = get_post_meta( 426, 'mphb_season_prices', true); and then print_r($var)

Comment: i tried and output: Array. 

Please check "Suggestion 2" from above.